ListContourPlot skipping over some colors
I'm trying to make two ListContourPlots with the same contour spacing and colors. One plot has a larger maximum value that seems to be screwing with the even color distribution in the plot:
data1={{17.58,31.56,37.75,108.4,31.19,6.694,1.084},{6.814,17.7,32.47,38.79,31.19,6.694,1.084},{2.206,6.869,18.34,34.87,23.16,6.694,1.084},{0.736,2.083,7.06,20.97,20.81,5.833,1.084},{0.1694,0.6364,2.079,8.16,12.78,5.486,1.084},{0.04068,0.1539,0.6099,2.229,4.654,4.333,0.9476},{0.009418,0.0365,0.1473,0.5622,1.128,1.988,0.8437},{0.002142,0.008397,0.03462,0.1382,0.2465,0.5569,0.5085},{0.0004828,0.001904,0.007927,0.03169,0.05958,0.1205,0.1789}};
data2={{19.15,27.83,30.68,32.37,14.24,3.259,0.5356},{9.017,17.98,27.96,29.4,14.24,3.259,0.5356},{3.734,8.595,18.18,27.71,12.92,3.259,0.5356},{2.117,3.51,8.672,18.88,12.31,2.981,0.5356},{0.2159,1.835,3.509,9.161,8.901,2.904,0.5356},{0.1125,0.2238,1.786,3.616,4.414,2.553,0.4854},{0.05856,0.1167,0.2365,1.625,1.676,1.519,0.4618},{0.03046,0.06072,0.1233,0.2806,0.6536,0.6363,0.3342},{0.01584,0.03159,0.06418,0.1463,0.2562,0.2296,0.165}};

{ListContourPlot[data1,Frame->True,PlotLegends->Automatic,Contours->{1,5,10,15,20,25,30}],
ListContourPlot[data2,Frame->True,PlotLegends->Automatic,Contours->{1,5,10,15,20,25,30}]}


Why are the two color profiles slightly different? I want the color distribution of the first plot to be the same as the second plot. I don't care about the out-of-range data in white on the first plot - it should be the same cream color as the surrounding contour.

Use explicit ContourShading. In the code comment there is also how to use other gradients.
data1 = {{17.58, 31.56, 37.75, 108.4, 31.19, 6.694, 1.084}, {6.814, 
    17.7, 32.47, 38.79, 31.19, 6.694, 1.084}, {2.206, 6.869, 18.34, 
    34.87, 23.16, 6.694, 1.084}, {0.736, 2.083, 7.06, 20.97, 20.81, 
    5.833, 1.084}, {0.1694, 0.6364, 2.079, 8.16, 12.78, 5.486, 
    1.084}, {0.04068, 0.1539, 0.6099, 2.229, 4.654, 4.333, 
    0.9476}, {0.009418, 0.0365, 0.1473, 0.5622, 1.128, 1.988, 
    0.8437}, {0.002142, 0.008397, 0.03462, 0.1382, 0.2465, 0.5569, 
    0.5085}, {0.0004828, 0.001904, 0.007927, 0.03169, 0.05958, 0.1205,
     0.1789}};
data2 = {{19.15, 27.83, 30.68, 32.37, 14.24, 3.259, 0.5356}, {9.017, 
    17.98, 27.96, 29.4, 14.24, 3.259, 0.5356}, {3.734, 8.595, 18.18, 
    27.71, 12.92, 3.259, 0.5356}, {2.117, 3.51, 8.672, 18.88, 12.31, 
    2.981, 0.5356}, {0.2159, 1.835, 3.509, 9.161, 8.901, 2.904, 
    0.5356}, {0.1125, 0.2238, 1.786, 3.616, 4.414, 2.553, 
    0.4854}, {0.05856, 0.1167, 0.2365, 1.625, 1.676, 1.519, 
    0.4618}, {0.03046, 0.06072, 0.1233, 0.2806, 0.6536, 0.6363, 
    0.3342}, {0.01584, 0.03159, 0.06418, 0.1463, 0.2562, 0.2296, 
    0.165}};

cont = {1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30} // Sort;

(*shade=ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#]&/@Rescale[Append[cont,Max[cont]\
+10]];*)

shade = Blend["M10DefaultDensityGradient", #] & /@ 
   Rescale[Append[cont, Max[cont] + 10]];


{ListContourPlot[data1, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  Contours -> cont, ContourShading -> shade], 
 ListContourPlot[data2, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  Contours -> cont, ContourShading -> shade]}



